# count and replace with awk while copying lines that meet criteria

Tags: awk

I have data in text files that looks something like this:

```
* *
18.442 24.661 32.45 53.061 62.039 100.303 113.257 123.638 131.444 142.779 149.064 
* *
* *
* *
27.788 49.938 132.166 139.538 
* *
12.224 19.48 29.61 36.646 57.56 107.559 114.111 122.871 135.943 145.89 
* *
14.162 21.568 28.105 34.322 42.914 52.978 100.12 106.172 112.79 
* *
* *
```

I want to use awk to count the number of entries on each line (count ".") is fine. If the line has only "*" then I want to copy the original line of the text file.

I want the output to look like this:

```
* *
11
* *
* *
* *
4
* *
10
* *
9
* *
* *
```

However, right now the best way to do this I can find is with:

```
awk -F\. '{print NF-1}' myfile.txt
```

but this obviously gives me 0's in the "*" rows.

Any ideas?

Comment: `awk '/^\*/{print;}!/^\*/{print NF;}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional operator to check whether record has only spaces and `*`s:

```
$ awk '{ print ( /[^ *]/ ? NF : $0 ) }' file
* *
11
* *
* *
* *
4
* *
10
* *
9
* *
* *
```

Comment: the solution works with or without $0~ in the above. Thanks!